# here image updated on database but not in directory

Tags: codeigniter

here controller page, here image name gets inserted into the database but the image does not go to the corresponding directory

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
      {  
     $config['upload_path']   = './upload/';
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|mp4';         

     $this->load->library('upload', $config);
     $this->upload->initialize($config);


        $data = array
        (
         'student_name' => $this->input->post('dname'),
         'student_email' => $this->input->post('demail'),
         'student_mobile' => $this->input->post('dmobile'),
         'student_address' => $this->input->post('daddress'),

            'picture' => $_FILES['picture']['name'] 
        );
     }

      $insertuserdata=$this->Inserts_model->form_insert($data);
```

here view page

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('Insert_ctrl/index/'); ?>"   
  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label>NAME</label>
  <input type="text" name="dname" required onkeyup="textt(this)"  
  id="name"><br>
  <label>email</label>
  <label>Picture</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="file" name="picture" /><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value ="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Remove `$this->upload->initialize($config);` line. If you pass second argument on loading class, you don't need to initialize class with config array.

Comment: @Tpojka hence no filgets in upload directory

Comment: You are not using upload function but expecting file being uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this

```
$config['upload_path']   = './upload/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|mp4';         

 $this->load->library('upload', $config);
 $this->upload->initialize($config);

if(!$this->upload->do_upload('picture'))
 {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
     print_r($error);
 }
 else{
    $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    print_r($data);
  }
```

Comment: i dont use do_upload function

Comment: @jibinkj then you need to use

Comment: @ Mayank Vadiya  hence no output

Comment: make sure you upload directory has proper permissions